# What are all Pandas .agg functions?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have some code like:

```
meanData = all_data.groupby(['Id'])[features].agg('mean')
```

This groups the data by `'Id'` value, selects the desired `features`, and aggregates each group by computing the `'mean'` of each group.

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), I know that the argument to `.agg` can be a string that names a function that will be used to aggregate the data.

I have also found that the valid strings include `'mean'`, `'median'`, `'sum'`, `'max'`, `'min'`, and `'std'` (standard deviation).

However, I cannot find a full list of these names in the documentation. What else can be done with `.agg`?

Answer (score 21):

You can find the full list in documentation under [GroupBy § Computations / descriptive stats](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html#computations-descriptive-stats).

List currently includes many aggregation functions:

all, any, bfill, backfill, count, cumcount, cummax, cummin, cumprod, cumsum, ffill, first, head, last, max, mean, median, min, ngroup, nth, ohlc, pad, prod, rank, pct_change, size, sem, std, sum, var, tail

> The following methods are available in both `SeriesGroupBy` and `DataFrameGroupBy` objects, but may differ slightly, usually in that the `DataFrameGroupBy` version usually permits the specification of an axis argument, and often an argument indicating whether to restrict application to columns of a specific data type.

all, any, backfill, bfill, corr, count, cov, cumcount, cummax, cummin, cumprod, cumsum, describe, diff, ffill, fillna, filter, hist, idxmax, idxmin, mad, nunique, pad, pct_change, plot, quantile, rank, resample, sample, shift, size, skew, take, tshift, value_counts

> The following methods are available only for `SeriesGroupBy` objects.

hist, nlargest, nsmallest, unique, is_monotonic_increasing, is_monotonic_decreasing

> The following methods are available only for `DataFrameGroupBy` objects.

corrwith, boxplot

Comment: @wjandrea can you add these?

Comment: I did one better and found a list with explanations in the documentation! And added the info here :)

Answer (score 6):

The aggregations that work with `.agg()` include:

Mean - `df.agg('mean')`

Median - `df.agg('median')`

Mode - `df.agg('mode')`

Sum - `df.agg('sum')`

Count - `df.agg('count')`

Max - `df.agg('max')`

Min - `df.agg('min')`

Standard Deviation - `df.agg('std')`

Variance - `df.agg('var')`

Skewness - `df.agg('skew')`

Kurtosis - `df.agg('kurt')`

Answer (score 4):

The relevant parts of `pandas/core/base.py` ([here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/base.py), line 298):

```
def _try_aggregate_string_function(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    if arg is a string, then try to operate on it:
    - try to find a function (or attribute) on ourselves
    - try to find a numpy function
    - raise

    """
    f = getattr(self, arg, None)
    if f is not None:
        if callable(f):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    f = getattr(np, arg, None)
    if f is not None:
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

    raise ValueError("{arg} is an unknown string function".format(arg=arg))
```

Essentially it tries to introspect using the string as a function, and then tries the same with numpy, in case it's a builtin. If not it returns a `ValueError`.

I'd be happy if someone who knows more than me could clarify more, but if not, hope this helps.

Comment: This has moved to [`apply.py`, currently line 526](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/apply.py#L526). They've also changed the NumPy check and now it excludes GroupBy objects.

Comment: A quirk of looking up the attribute on the `GroupBy` object is that you can even call non-aggregators like `__iter__` or do silly things like `.agg('agg', 'mean')`.