# Pandas: New Column that is division of groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
Attr1, Attr2, ... , AttrN, Val, Flag
   a1,  b1.1, ... ,    N1, 100,    A
   a2,  b2.1, ... ,    N2, 200,    A 
   a1,  b1.2, ... ,    N1,  20,    B
   a2,  b2.2, ... ,    N2,  50,    B
```

Basically, the table can be divided in two regions. `Flag==A` and `Flag==B`. There is always an `A` row that corresponds to a `B` row. Correspond means that a certain subset of Columns `AttrX` match exactly, here `Attr1`, However, some `Attr`, here `Attr2` contain floating point values that are not guaranteed to match. Also, there is the column `Val` containing the actual quantity of interest.

What I now would like to have is a reordering like this:

```
Attr1, Attr2A, Attr2B, ... , AttrN, Val_A/B
   a1,   b1.1,   b1.2, ... ,    N1,       5
   a2,   b2.1,   b2.2, ... ,    N2,       4
```

Common Attributes should be merged, differing attributes should get a column for both values of `Flag`, and the entries of the column `Val` shall be divided (A/B).

Comment: You can use from pivot_table method for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possible way to do this:

```py
# pivot your table
res = pd.pivot_table(
    data=df, 
    index=['Attr1'],
    columns=['Flag'], 
    values=['Attr2','AttrN','Val'],
    aggfunc='first')
# print(res.columns)
# columns are a Multiindex now, looking like this: [('Attr2', 'A'),('Attr2', 'B'),...]
# join it to single level
res.columns= res.columns.map(''.join)

# calculation
res['ValA'] = res['ValA'].div(res['ValB'])

# drop unnecessary column and rename 'ValA'
res = res.drop('ValB',axis=1).rename(columns={'ValA' : 'Val'}).reset_index()
```

Output `res`:

```
  Attr1 Attr2A Attr2B AttrNA AttrNB   Val
0    a1   b1.1   b1.2     N1     N1   5.0
1    a2   b2.1   b2.2     N2     N2   4.0
```

I assume there is a little mistake in your desired output and the Nth Attr also has column A and B in the end?

**EDIT**
Explanation on `aggfunc`: `first`

When pivoting it is possible that you have multiple values for one field. aggfunc defines how to handle them. If not passing an aggfunc, `np.mean` is the default, but mean only works for numerical data, so in your data all columns except `Val` would be missing. Since you don't have duplicates, `first` will just get the first (and only one) value of each (and every!) group.

Here is your data with another row added (row 1) for demonstration:

```
   Attr1  Attr2 AttrN   Val Flag
0     a1   b1.1    N1   100    A
1     a1  b11.1   N11  1001    A
2     a2   b2.1    N2   200    A
3     a1   b1.2    N1    20    B
4     a2   b2.2    N2    50    B
```

For `index=['Attr1']` and `columns=['Flag']` you have more than one value now. But in your pivot row 1 never occurs because it is in the same group than row 0 and we only take the `first` value.
You can try out what happens if you skip aggfunc, or use `last` instead of `first`. Maybe it gets clearer then.

I'm not sure if that is totally accurate what I'm saying, but aggfunc takes every function (also custom functions of your own) which works on a DataFrame with the condition that the function reduces a group of values to a single output value (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943319/what-are-all-python-pandas-agg-functions) question for more details)

Comment: Can you explain `aggfunc='first'`? I can't seem to find documentation on this.