# How can i transform the dataset so that one line has one id based on column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have such type of dataset

[image: 1]

and want to do this dataset based on column 't_value'

[image: 2]

I am pretty new to Python, I understand that we need to use loop but in what way? Also i dont know how to insert attractive tables with data( I would be gratfull for any help!

Comment: Since your expected result looks strange to me (multiple sex etc) : Do you want to do further analyses? In this case `groupby("t_value")` might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend **using loops to `.pivot` the DataFrame, and then merging them.**

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial, reduce

required_cols = ['age', 'sex', 'temp']

df_dict = {}

for col in applied_cols:
    df[f'{col}_suffix'] = col + '_' + df['t_value'].astype(str)

    temp_df = df.pivot(index='id', columns=f'{col}_suffix', values=col).reset_index()
    df_dict[f'{col}_pivot'] = temp_df
    
merge_df = partial(pd.merge, on='id')
reduce(merge_df, df_dict.values())
```

### Step 0: Creating DataFrame

Recreating DataFrame using the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
        'age': [20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40],
        'sex': ['m', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm'],
        'temp': [36.6, 37, 37.5, 38, 36, 35, 37, 36, 36, 37, 38, 35], 
        't_value': [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
    id  age sex temp    t_value
0   1   20  m   36.6    0
1   1   20  m   37.0    1
2   1   20  m   37.5    2
3   1   20  m   38.0    3
4   2   30  f   36.0    0
5   2   30  f   35.0    2
6   2   30  f   37.0    3
7   2   30  f   36.0    1
8   3   40  m   36.0    3
9   3   40  m   37.0    2
10  3   40  m   38.0    1
11  3   40  m   35.0    0
```

### Step 1: Create new columns with *values* that will become *column names* in the final DataFrame

Currently, you do not have columns to pivot the table. We will create these using a for loop over the required column names:

```
required_cols = ['age', 'sex', 'temp']

for col in applied_cols:
    df[f'{col}_suffix'] = col + '_' + df['t_value'].astype(str)
```

Output:

```
id  age sex temp    t_value age_suffix  sex_suffix  temp_suffix
0   1   20  m   36.6    0   age_0   sex_0   temp_0
1   1   20  m   37.0    1   age_1   sex_1   temp_1
2   1   20  m   37.5    2   age_2   sex_2   temp_2
```

### Step 2: Pivot tables on the new columns

We will create a dictionary to hold these different pivot tables, then use a for loop to `[pivot()][1]` the DataFrame:

```
df_dict = {}

for col in applied_cols:
    temp_df = df.pivot(index='id', columns=f'{col}_suffix', values=col).reset_index()
    df_dict[f'{col}_pivot'] = temp_df
```

Output:

```
# table 1
age_suffix  id  age_0   age_1   age_2   age_3
0   1   20  20  20  20
1   2   30  30  30  30
2   3   40  40  40  40

# table 2
sex_suffix  id  sex_0   sex_1   sex_2   sex_3
0   1   m   m   m   m
1   2   f   f   f   f
2   3   m   m   m   m

# table 3
temp_suffix id  temp_0  temp_1  temp_2  temp_3
0   1   36.6    37.0    37.5    38.0
1   2   36.0    36.0    35.0    37.0
2   3   35.0    38.0    37.0    36.0
```

### Step 3: we merge all three DataFrames into one

Here, we use a combination of `pd.merge` and `functools`:

```
from functools import partial, reduce

merge_df = partial(pd.merge, on='id')
reduce(merge_df, df_dict.values())
```

Output:

```
id  age_0   age_1   age_2   age_3   sex_0   sex_1   sex_2   sex_3   temp_0  temp_1  temp_2  temp_3
0   1   20  20  20  20  m   m   m   m   36.6    37.0    37.5    38.0
1   2   30  30  30  30  f   f   f   f   36.0    36.0    35.0    37.0
2   3   40  40  40  40  m   m   m   m   35.0    38.0    37.0    36.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_table()` from `pandas`

try:

```
new_df = pd.pivot_table(
            df,   # the first dataframe
            index = "id",  # aggregating column
            columns = "t_value"  # mapped column
            aggfunc = "first"
         )

# merge the multiindex columns 
new_df.columns = [x[0] + "_" + str(x[1]) for x in new_df.columns]

#reset index to retrieve "id" column
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

It is better than a 'for-loop'.

[My reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73168057/13707709)

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby(['id', 'age', 'sex']).cumcount()
df1 = pd.pivot(df[['id','idx', 'age']],index = ['id'] ,values=['age'],  columns=['idx']).add_prefix('age_')
df2 = pd.pivot(df[['id','idx', 'sex']],index = ['id'] ,values=['sex'],  columns=['idx']).add_prefix('sex_')
df3 = pd.pivot(df[['id','idx', 'temp']],index = ['id'] ,values=['temp'],  columns=['idx']).add_prefix('temp_')

df_final = df1.join(df2).join(df3)
print(df_final)
```