# Pandas Groupby and Compare rows to find maximum value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exploratory-data-analysis

I've a dataframe

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | 6 | 11 |
| one | 7 | 12 |
| two | 8 | 23 |
| two | 9 | 14 |
| three | 10 | 15 |
| three | 20 | 25 |

I want to apply `groupby at column a` and then find the `highest value in column c`, so that, the highest value gets flagged, i.e.

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | 6 | 11 |
| one | 7 | 12 |

Compare value 11&12, then

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| two | 8 | 23 |
| two | 9 | 14 |

Compare value 23&14, then

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| three | 10 | 15 |
| three | 20 | 25 |

Finally resulting in:

| a | b | c | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | 6 | 11 | no |
| one | 7 | 12 | yes |
| two | 8 | 23 | yes |
| two | 9 | 14 | no |
| three | 10 | 15 | no |
| three | 20 | 25 | yes |

---

**I/P DF**:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':["one","one","two","two","three","three"]
    , 'b':[6,7,8,9,10,20]
    , 'c':[11,12,23,14,15,25]
    # , 'flag': ['no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes']
})
df
```

Comment: If there is multiple maximum valeus whats happens? 2 times `yes` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get the max value per group, and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to map the `True`/`False` to `'yes'`/`'no'`:

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('max').eq(df['c']), 'yes', 'no')
```

output:

```
       a   b   c flag
0    one   6  11   no
1    one   7  12  yes
2    two   8  23  yes
3    two   9  14   no
4  three  10  15   no
5  three  20  25  yes
```

Intermediates:

```
df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('max')

0    12
1    12
2    23
3    23
4    25
5    25
Name: c, dtype: int64

df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('max').eq(df['c'])
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: c, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway for again coming to rescue. One small follow up question though, any good documentation/webpage where I can find list of possible functions name that can be used with `.transform()`, as the official doc doesn't includes function list

Comment: You can check the [reference for `agg`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943319/what-are-all-python-pandas-agg-functions), there is no fixed list, it depends of what the parser can find ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `max`, comapre to same column `c` and then set `yes/no` in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df.c.eq(df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('max')), 'yes', 'no')

print(df)
       a   b   c flag
0    one   6  11   no
1    one   7  12  yes
2    two   8  23  yes
3    two   9  14   no
4  three  10  15   no
5  three  20  25  yes
```

If multiple values per `a` with maximal values get multiple `yes`, if need only first maximal values use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and compare `df.index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':["one","one","one","two","three","three"]
    , 'b':[6,7,8,9,10,20]
    , 'c':[11,12,12,14,15,25]
})

df['flag1'] = np.where(df.c.eq(df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('max')), 'yes', 'no')
df['flag2'] = np.where(df.index == df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('idxmax'), 'yes', 'no')

print(df)

       a   b   c flag1 flag2
0    one   6  11    no    no
1    one   7  12   yes   yes
2    one   8  12   yes    no <- difference for match all max or first max
3    two   9  14   yes   yes
4  three  10  15    no    no
5  three  20  25   yes   yes
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is as follows

```
df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'yes' if x['c'] in df.groupby('a')['c'].max().values and x['a'] == df.groupby('c')['a'].max().loc[x['c']] else 'no', axis=1)

       a   b   c flag
0    one   6  11   no
1    one   7  12  yes
2    two   8  23  yes
3    two   9  14   no
4  three  10  15   no
5  three  20  25  yes
```

---

Breaking down the various steps that one is doing above

- `df['flag']` creates the new column named `flag`.
- `df.groupby('a')['c'].max()` will group by column `a`, with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), and find the highest value in column `c`.

  ```
   df2 = df.groupby('a')['c'].max()
  ```
- Then we check if the value is in the dataframe generated in step 2 **AND** if the group is the same.

  ```
   df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'yes' if x['c'] in df2.values and x['a'] == df2.loc[x['c']] else 'no', axis=1)
  ```

**Notes:**

- Checking if the group is the same is key, else, even though it was working for this specific case, it wouldn't work if a group had a non-max value that was the max value of another group (as mozway mentioned).
- As [indicated in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/7109869) that [jezrael shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73783447/pandas-groupby-and-compare-rows-to-find-maximum-value/73783530?noredirect=1#comment130286656_73783530), `.apply` can be slow and, even though does the work, it might not be the most convenient way to do that.